# Calculating the Standard Deviations for Percentages

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, percentage

I have a data-set consisting of the Analytical and Label nutrient values for certain food (their mean and standard deviations). I was checking the consistency of the calculations. I believe that there are two major flaws with this analysis and would be glad if someone could address them.

1. The Mean Percentage discrepancy has been calculated by taking the average of the percentage discrepancy of each row (highlighted). I think that one should not take the averages of percentages which are unrelated (Each percent is defined for different nutrients). However, I would love if someone could confirm this.
2. The standard deviation for Mean Discrepancy percentage is just the standard deviation of percentage Discrepancy (% Discrep). Is it a correct way to compute the standard deviation? I feel that the standard deviation of the Analytical and label values do not reflect in this value of standard deviation.

[image: Nutrient's value table]

Comment: I can't see that averages of percentages are wrong in principle. They might not be the right answer, but that depends on the question. Similarly the SD of percentages is what it is and not _ipso facto_ wrong. If all percents are  0 then the SD necessarily is 0 too, but the same applies to 100% $=$ 1, so you might need to be subtle, e.g. work on logit scales, except that exact zeros and ones can then be awkward . For small percents that are not zero, SD of logarithms might work best; that idea is compatible with logit to the extent that logit $p \approx$  logarithm of $p$ for small $p$.

Comment: Hi Nick. The thing is I am getting different results for both the approaches for calculating the Mean Discrepancy percentage. So, i need to be really sure of the approach.

Comment: I don't see (a) which results are different (b) any indication of what both approaches mean. I just see what looks like a chunk of a spreadsheet.